# TypeLoadException: Could not load type, but type is from an old namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting this error

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type abc.Infrastructure.Providers.Identity.Entities.UserProfile' from assembly abc.Infrastructure.Providers.Data, Version=1.2.6.1.`

when I hit this line  `services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();` during the configuration services.

`abc.Infrastructure.Providers` used to be the namespace that `Identity.Entities.UserProfile` (and many, many more types that are throwing the same error) were in.  I changed the namespace and updated the nuget package to be `abc.Infrastructure.Providers.Data` along with all the respective class inside the package.  Now `abc.Infrastructure.Providers.Data.Identity.Entities.UserProfile` is the correct path to that type.

The problem is I don't understand why the aspnetcore app is trying to reference the old namespaces.  I have deleted bin and obj folders, thinking maybe it was getting confused with old assemblies.  I have cleaned the project.  Is there virtual folder I am missing where the assemblies might be cached?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you have that namespace in ViewImports or somewhere in your code, just do a global search

Comment: @JoeAudette I tried that.  its an webapi project so no views anywhere, also did a search of the namespace everywhere didnt find it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be NuGet package cache. Assuming you bumped the version of your package as you should have, that shouldn't be an issue, but I'd still kill the cache anyway to just to be sure.

Go to **Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Manager Settings**. Then, click the **"Clear All NuGet Cache(s)"** button there. Afterwards **Rebuild your solution**.

Comment: I am going to mark this correct as it lead me down the path.  The problem was that I have not updated all the NuGet packages that had the offending package as a dependency.